# MYSQL Calling stored procedures inside an SELECT CASE on a Trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, mysql-error-1064

im stuck on calling stored procedures inside a SELECT CASE on a Trigger, it gaves me the following error:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'empata(NEW.eqvis))
            WHEN 'loc' THEN pierde(NEW.eqvis)
            WHEN 'vis' THEN g' at line 16
```

Here is the code:

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER updpartido AFTER UPDATE ON partidos
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SET @vgls = vgoles(NEW.eqvis);
        SET @lgls = vgoles(NEW.eqloc);
        SET @vglsec = vgolesec(NEW.eqvis);
        SET @lglsec = vgolesec(NEW.eqloc);
        SELECT CASE 
            WHEN @vgls=@lgls THEN "emp"
            WHEN @vgls>@lgls THEN "loc"
            WHEN @vgls<@lgls THEN "vis" 
        END
        INTO @st;

        SELECT CASE @st
            WHEN 'emp' THEN CALL empata(NEW.eqvis)
            WHEN 'loc' THEN CALL pierde(NEW.eqvis)
            WHEN 'vis' THEN CALL gana(NEW.eqvis)
        END
        INTO @dat;

        SELECT CASE @st
            WHEN 'emp' THEN CALL empata(NEW.eqloc)
            WHEN 'vis' THEN CALL pierde(NEW.eqloc)
            WHEN 'loc' THEN CALL gana(NEW.eqloc)
        END
        INTO @dat2;

        UPDATE equipos SET gf=@vgls,gc=@vglsec WHERE id=NEW.eqvis;
        UPDATE equipos SET gf=@lgls,gc=@lglsec WHERE id=NEW.eqloc;
    END;
```

|

But if i remove the "CALL" the Triggers adds but when i do some update it gives me the error of "FUNCTION not found" since i made them as stored procedures and not as functions because im not going to return nothing...

Any help is very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your procedures `empata`, `pierde`, and `gana` into functions and use as coded in the first example below:

```php
-- works
SET @st = 'loc';
SELECT CASE @st
  WHEN 'loc' THEN function_(@st)
END
INTO @dat;
SELECT @dat;
```

I tested the following scenarios and they didn't work:

```
-- won't work
SET @st = 'loc';
IF @st = 'loc' THEN
    function_(@st);
END IF;

-- won't work
SET @st = 'loc';
SELECT CASE @st
  WHEN 'loc' THEN CALL stored_procedure_(@st)
END
INTO @dat;
SELECT @dat;

-- won't work
SET @st = 'loc';
IF @st = 'loc' THEN
    CALL stored_procedure_(@st);
END IF;
```

At the very least, they didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to adventure an answer even though I'm not a MySQL guy:

I don't think you can call stored procedures within a select statement whose output is stored in a variable; or more colloquially:  You can't blow and suck at the same time. You either have have a select statement whose purpose is to return some records or you execute some kind of process on your data, but you can't have both intertwined.

If you separate the `CALL` statements I think it should work. You can do the check below the `into @...` and call the appropriate stored proc.

Comment: Its a bit confusing, what i want to do is a trigger that adds if a team has more score than the other, it adds a victory for one and lose for other, also adds an matches played

Comment: That's easy enough, so why do you need to call another stored procedure to do that? And why do you `insert into @dat` after you do the `select...`?

Comment: @EnriqueBenitez I assume it's because functions cannot change data where as stored procedures can. Again, I'm not a mysql guy, but at least on SQL Server you can't update data within a function.

Comment: the "(at)dat" variable is just because a trigger cannot return a "dataset", and thats why i did it...