# SELECT CASE and CALL procedures on MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

im trying to do the following

```
SELECT CASE @st
  WHEN 'emp' THEN CALL empata(NEW.eqvis)
  WHEN 'loc' THEN CALL pierde(NEW.eqvis)
  WHEN 'vis' THEN CALL gana(NEW.eqvis)
END
INTO @dat;
```

But i got this:

```
[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CALL empata(NEW.eqvis)
                    WHEN 'loc' THEN CALL pierde(NEW.eqvis)
                    WHEN' at line 18
```

But if i remove the "Call" i got an `"Function db.xxx not found"`

What im doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871260/mysql-calling-stored-procedures-inside-an-select-case-on-a-trigger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your procedures `empata`, `pierde`, and `gana` into functions and use as coded in the first example below:

```sql
-- works
SET @st = 'loc';
SELECT CASE @st
  WHEN 'loc' THEN function_(@st)
END
INTO @dat;
SELECT @dat;
```

I tested the following scenarios and they didn't work:

```
-- won't work
SET @st = 'loc';
IF @st = 'loc' THEN
    function_(@st);
END IF;

-- won't work
SET @st = 'loc';
SELECT CASE @st
  WHEN 'loc' THEN CALL stored_procedure_(@st)
END
INTO @dat;
SELECT @dat;

-- won't work
SET @st = 'loc';
IF @st = 'loc' THEN
    CALL stored_procedure_(@st);
END IF;
```

At the very least, none of the three instances above worked for me.. You can try them and see which one works for yourself.

Also, your question here is the same as: [MYSQL Calling stored procedures inside an SELECT CASE on a Trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871260/mysql-calling-stored-procedures-inside-an-select-case-on-a-trigger) ..also posted by you. I'm not sure which one the moderators will close or retain, so I'm posting this answer there too. If, on another occasion, you'd like to follow up on a question you asked that hasn't received an answer acceptable to you, just bump it up so people can see it again.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a procedure (using CALL) in this situation, it has to be a [function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html).